JSON Value Become Invalid (cut to 255 characeters)
I posted 2 weeks ago question about invalid JSON.
In short: it seems that my code was unable to desterilize JSON that was queried from data.
I asked if it is possible that somehow the data return only 255 characters, despite the field is a long text and answered that this is very unlikely. Back them, I checked the data and it was a valid JSON.
However, now I've a similar error, but I can see that the JSON is invalid (and somehow it cut at 255 characters)
Exception details: Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value at [line:1, column:511]

it is missing the end:  e"}
{"processVersion":"v2","relatedIds":["500Vz00000CBSdBIAX_a6pVz000001B7SDIA0","500Vz00000C5n1DIAR_a6pVz000001B7QbIAK","500Vz00000C2APRIA3_a6pVz000001B7GvIAK","500Vz00000C9wcAIAR_a6pVz000001B7GvIAK","500Vz00000CS8mzIAD_a6pVz000001B7QbIAK"],"objectName":"Cas

Obviously, this can happen only when a process cut the value, but I didn't find any place where my code might using left/substring. My code, prepare the data in a map and at the end store the value in a field, this is both when the record is being created and when it is updated
Map<String, object> params = new Map<String, object>();
//fill the map...
rec.Params__c = JSON.serialize(params);

It is one failure out of thousands of records, but I couldn't find something unique about it.
Out of other idea, I'm wondering if it might happened due to internal issue, such as parallel processing, heap size or something similar? Does someone had a similar issue where JSON value is not being saved properly?
UPDATE
I decided to tackle the issue by load the system with processes.
I wrote an batch apex code. The batch run 100 iterations, and each time query records with JSON value and randomly manipulate a record.
I set log during the process and wrote it to a logger object in case of a JSON error.
Ran 5 batches of this process in parallel, several times and in a very few cases got this error.
Can definitely see in the log that 1 record was received with invalid JSON (cut to 255 characters). I printed the value as it was received from the query (before any manipulation).
(third line):
setting job a018c00000oyCH6AAM params: {"objectName":"Case","relatedIds":["5008c00001ZKgW4AAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgW9AAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgW6AAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgVvAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgVwAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgW8AAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgWCAA1_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgVyAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgWKAA1_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgWMAA1_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgWOAA1_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgWIAA1_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgWTAA1_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgWYAA1_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgWjAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgDpAAL_a088c00001QbuQXAAZ","5008c00001ZKgVPAA1_a088c00001QbuP7AAJ","5008c00001ZKgXlAAL_a088c00001QbuP7AAJ","5008c00001ZKgMSAA1_a088c00001QbuQXAAZ","5008c00001ZKgPMAA1_a088c00001QbuQXAAZ","5008c00001ZKgBRAA1_a088c00001QbuQXAAZ","5008c00001ZKgQ3AAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgVlAAL_a088c00001QbuP7AAJ","5008c00001ZKgNgAAL_a088c00001QbuQXAAZ"]}
checking job a018c00000oyCHLAA2 params: {"objectName":"Case","relatedIds":["5008c00001ZKgViAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgWeAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgWfAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgX4AAL_a088c00001QbuP7AAJ","5008c00001ZKgVCAA1_a088c00001QbuP7AAJ","5008c00001ZKgOsAAL_
checking job a018c00000oyBssAAE params: {"objectName":"Case","relatedIds":["5008c00001ZKgE1AAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgDmAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgJmAAL_a088c00001QbuQXAAZ","5008c00001ZKgJCAA1_a088c00001QbuP7AAJ","5008c00001ZKgRdAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgJoAAL_a088c00001QbuQXAAZ","5008c00001ZKgOwAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgUrAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgV2AAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgUpAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgUqAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgV6AAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgUlAAL_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ","5008c00001ZKgVGAA1_a088c00001QbuP9AAJ"]}

When looking at the record right now the JSON is complete and valid.
I'm still not sure why this happened, but it seems to me either related to parallel processing that update the same records or to the volume of data (or both).
And yet, I'm also not sure how exactly to repreduce it, except of overload processing.

Note that if the field is a long text area in a custom metadata type record and you use getInstance to read the data, this IS truncated to 255 characters. To read the whole value you must use SOQL to query the data instead. This is, of course, a different scenario than that you raised here, by the look of it.

@PhilW Thanks. But it is a custom object, not a metadata
